# Possible to communicate with a remote actor from a non-actor?

Tags: scala, akka

I know that you can send messages and receive a response from outside an actor if you use `ask` (`?` syntax). The problem is I don't know if this can be done when the actor is remote. By 'outside an actor' I mean from normal non-actor code. Can a non-actor talk to a remote actor?

[] is the process boundary and capitalization means its an actor. Previously the set up was this and was working fine:

[**a** **B**]

However now I'm trying to make B remote:

[**a**] [**B**]

I could probably get it to work if I gave [**a**] a local actor, but that should not be necessary.

In **a** there is no `ActorContext`, only an `ActorSystem`. Here is the code I am trying to use (`remote` is **B**):

```
val systemName = "THIS_UNIVERSE"
// other vals: remoteIP, remotePort, remoteActorName - all to do with B
val actorSystem = ActorSystem(systemName)
...
val str = s"akka.tcp://$systemName@$remoteIP:$remotePort/user/$remoteActorName"
actorSystem.actorSelection(str).resolveOne().onComplete {
  ...
}
```

As you can see even the syntax does not make much sense: there's already an `actorSystem`, yet in the protocol String `systemName` needs to be used.

Is communicating with a remote actor from a non actor possible? I haven't found any examples to use as reference.

I do actually know that **B** is running and in fact it already has another actor that is able to find it and communicate with it.

For the purpose of this question I have just now set up a stand alone Scala program that creates an actor and tries to get an actorRef to **B**, in a similar manner to the code above. But no joy:

```
Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://THIS_UNIVERSE/deadLetters), Path(/user/MyPLC)]
```

Is it the case that this standalone program will need to have an `application.conf` available to be loaded? i.e. without such a file it won't be able to find remote actors?

Great - the standalone program can find the remote actor when a `src/main/resources/application.conf` file is present for sbt to pick up.

So back to the original question: [**a**] by definition won't have an `application.conf` file in its class-path as it is not an actor. However I'll put one in and see if it helps...

That helped! In this case `application.conf` was put at the root of one of the dependent jar files.

So the answer to the question is that you can communicate from a non-actor, however you still need most of the actor stuff - the actor jar files and an `application.conf` on the class-path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to.

If you are able to communicate from a local actor to the remote, [A] [B], then have B send a message to A, then print the sender's path to make sure you have the correct path.

Regarding the syntax, `systemName` is the remote actor system's name.  `actorSystem` in your example is the local actor system.

You could have your non-actor code ask the local actor for the remote actor's ref. For example:

```
val remoteRefFuture = A ? GetRemoteAddress
remoteRefFuture.mapTo[ActorRef].foreach { B => B ! Xyz }
```

Double check the IP address in the path and make sure it matches exactly the IP address or hostname you are using in the remoting configuration on the remote side.

Here's a small runnable example.  Run two instances of this app.  Start the first with command line parameter `2550`.  Then start the second with `2551`.

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import akka.pattern.ask
import akka.util.Timeout

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.util.Success
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object AskRemote extends App {
  val port = args(0).toInt
  val configStr =
    s"""
       |akka {
       |  actor {
       |    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
       |  }
       |  remote {
       |    enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
       |    netty.tcp {
       |      hostname = "localhost"
       |      port = $port
       |    }
       |  }
       |}
      """.stripMargin
  val config = ConfigFactory.parseString(configStr)
  val system = ActorSystem(s"system$port", config)

  if (port == 2550) {
    system.actorOf(Props(new MyActor), "myActor")
    system.awaitTermination()

  } else {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(5.seconds)
    val path = s"akka.tcp://system2550@localhost:2550/user/myActor"

    system.actorSelection(path).resolveOne().onComplete {
      case Success(ref) =>
        val fut = ref ? "hello"
        println(Await.result(fut, 5.seconds))
        system.shutdown()
    }
  }
}

class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case s: String =>
      println(s"got $s")
      sender() ! s"you sent $s"
      context.system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

Comment: Here you have made [**A**] an actor. But [**a**] is just a normal non-actor that needs access to [**B**]. [**a**] is just a process that wants to *synchronously* (using `?` and `Await`) ask questions of [**B**], which is *hardware*.

Comment: I don't follow - you said "capitalization means its an actor" and your `str` path example is a path to an actor.  What I am suggesting is either 1) set up a local actor temporarily just to verify that the remote path is correct or 2) use a local actor anyway as the intermediary between the remote and your non-actor code.  You're going to need an actor system on the local side to use `?` (`ask`), it won't hurt to have a local actor mediating.

Comment: Just added a note about making sure the IP address in the path is correct.

Comment: **a** was never capitalized - it is like the UI for your mouse. I think the answer is no, not unless you use a workaround of giving **a** a local actor. When I had [**a** **B**] I did have access to a local actor - **B**. I've now lost that local actor but need to re-introduce it. The question I'm asking is if it is possible not to have to re-introduce some local actor.

Comment: I meant B.  B is an actor, right, not actual hardware?  Yes, it is possible to send to a remote actor from an `ask`.  You just need to make sure the path is correct.  If it's not working then the path is not correct.  The easiest way to debug that is to create a local actor.

Comment: What is the the value of `remoteIP` and what is the value of `akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname` in your remote system's config?

Comment: B is an actor yes. Both `remoteIP` and `akka.remote.netty.tcp.hostname` (from application.conf) are "127.0.0.1". I'll try out the local actor approach next. Wish there was something like 'Angry Ant' (port scanner) for actors!

Comment: I see the confusion now, sorry. When I put *hardware* in *italics* the meaning that was supposed to be inferred was virtual hardware. **B** is an actor. Because it is *hardware* is a good reason for it to be standalone,  remote, and communicated with synchronously by non actors - that's all.

Comment: I added a sample program for testing.  I ran this successfully on my end.